# Rails param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Hi there, I'm getting the error :
param is missing or the value is empty: campaign**

**I have a link to create a new campaign:**

```
<%= button_to 'Start 14 days free trial', select_campaign_type_path(campaign_type: 1), method: :patch, class: 'py-4 px-10 w-full text-white font-semibold rounded-xl focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-300 bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 transition ease-in-out duration-200' %>
```

**In my controller action:**

```
  def select_campaign_type
    @campaign = current_user.campaigns.build(campaign_params)
    redirect_to new_campaign_path(@campaign), status: :see_other and return if @campaign.campaign_type.blank?

    respond_to do |format|
      if @campaign.save
        puts "Hey"
        format.html { redirect_to step1_campaign_path(@campaign), status: :found }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**In my campaign params:**

```
def campaign_params
  params.require(:campaign).permit(:campaign, :campaign_type)
end
```

**Routes**

```
patch :select_campaign_type, to: "campaigns#select_campaign_type", as: :select_campaign_type
```

**If I remove the require(:campaign), then I will get the same error with :utf8, _authenticity_token and :method.**

Comment: I suspect it's because you're not passing a `campaign` object or going through a standard form when submitting. Usually you'd have a form with `form_for @campaign`, which in the params would generate the parameter it's complaining about not having.

You might try looking at the params being passed in the server log or `puts params.inspect` at the beginning of the controller action, you'll see exaclty what is being passed.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the route for the select_campaign_type action is defined correctly in your routes.rb file. It should be a PATCH request pointing to the appropriate controller and action.

Comment: I have this route:
patch :select_campaign_type, to: "campaigns#select_campaign_type", as: :select_campaign_type

Comment: Just fyi, they'd not get this error if the route was incorrect. They are hitting the action but missing a parameter they have required via `campaign_params`.